# Can you connect a 12 V transformer and a 12 V solar cell in parallel?

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell

I have a circuit that needs 12 V. I power it from a 12 V wall transformer. Could I save energy by connecting a 12 V solar cell in parallel, or would the transformer feed the solar cell when the sun is down?

Comment: Hi Ville, thanks for Notrium and Ekapeli. It is unlikely that those two can be directly connected in parallel without further electronics. The panel produces either more or less voltage depending on how much sun shines on it, and will likely need a MPPT controller to get the most power out of it. It would also back-feed power to the mains adapter, or the mains adapter would back-feed the panel, if there are no diodes to keep them separated. What kind of setup you have?

Comment: Solar panels behave kinda like batteries. Do you know what would happen if you put a battery in parallel?

Comment: A "transformer" outputs AC. You mean a mains-DC power supply.

Comment: I have a 12v power supply running some fans, and I have an extra 12v solar cell. I do have a lot of diodes available, would it really work by just adding one to each wire? And thanks Jusme!

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far, and thanks for the kudos Justme! It actually surprised me quite a bit that you recognized me as the Instant Kingdom game developer just from my name. But the assumption is correct. Always nice to hear from someone who's played (I presume) some of my games. :)

Comment: @user253751, That's only true if you think that a constant-voltage source is "kinda like" a constant-current source. I mean, they _are_ "kinda like" in the sense that both can supply power to a circuit, but check out [this tutorial](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/alm1k/alm-lab-pv) if you want to learn more about how PV cells really behave.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the same *concepts* apply - after understanding vaguely how the energy will flow, then we can look at the I/V curves. I gather that the asker has basically no idea at all how to analyze the scenario, and a battery is an easier scenario.

Comment: @user253751, Its like telling somebody that investing in commodities futures is kinda like managing a car wash because they can make a living either way. The same concepts apply; cash flow, supply and demand, economic opportunity,... It's like they're practically the same thing.

Comment: My research tells me that to actually utilize the solar power when it is available, the voltage from the solar panel needs to be higher than from the grid connected power supply. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both have reverse diodes then that may be done, if you know what to expect.  Normally an ACDC transformer has the diodes already.

- added

A 12V Solar panel usually comes with an MPPT Solar load controller and a lead acid battery output charger. As such, the panel max power voltage Vmp may be 18V (or 20V with no load) or the same time as the charger puts our 14.2V to the 12V battery.

Comment: Bad advice IMO. OP's circuit "needs 12V." What does that mean? The phrase "12V solar panel" usually means a panel that is suitable for connection to a solar charge controller for a 12V battery. The open-circuit voltage from such a panel in full sunlight could be more than 20V. We don't know how big the panel is. We don't know how much current OP's device will draw. Blindly connecting the panel and the device's normal power supply (through diodes, of course) could have exactly the effect that OP wanted, or it could do nothing, or go up in smoke. We don't have enough information to know which.

Comment: @SolomonSlow It's only bad if you "don't know what to expect" but it "may be done"  as Diode OR logic . The load is a big unknown and logic must govern the user's choice of solar panel-compatible loads over a wide range of voltages with no load or full load. I'll add some info.*

Comment: My load is four computer fans rated 12V, 2,4W. My wall power supply is rated 12V 2.5A, and my solar panel is rated 12V 100W. And you're right, the panel does give anything from 0 to 20 volts. I have an extra 12V voltage regulator that I've tested on it. The regulator works ok keeping the voltage at about 12V when the sun is up, but obviously the voltage drops when the sun goes down.

Comment: Will it be enough to place diodes in the positive leads?

Comment: YES 10W load @ 12V will be slightly less at 11.3V with a diode drop.  30W supply is fine, 100W PV will only have a capacity of 12/18V 66W max at 12V is adequate also.  So at 10cents/kwh you are saving how much?

Comment: Might be saving up to 2 dollars/euros per year, since I don't need the fans all year round.  :) I guess it's more about the fun of doing it rather than actually saving some money.